# На что будут неблагоприятно влиять измененные параметры в php.ini?

Tags: php.ini, php

```
max_execution_time = 1800 ;
max_input_time = 1800 ; 
memory_limit = 128M ;
upload_max_filesize = 900M ;
post_max_size = 900M ;
```

Вот поменял параметры на сервере для личных целей

Как эти изменения могут не благоприятно сказаться на работе сервера в целом?

Answer (score 3):

1. Если скрипт глюканет, будете полчаса ждать, пока отпустит
2. Аналогично.
3. Очень сильно нагружает сервер. А если запросов будет 2? 10? 20? Учтите, это вполне реальные цифры даже для никому неизвестного проекта: за полчаса же!!!
4. Это ограничение все равно перекроет ограничение на загружаемый файл. Только еще и ошибку выдаст, мол, переполнение отведенной памяти.
5. На фоне всего остального - цветочки.

P.S. чтоб вам гиг туда кто-то начал заливать. ^__^

UPD: а если серьезно, рассмотрите способы разбивки файла при загрузке. Чем-то типа флэша.

Comment: на сайте нет форм

Comment: Без разницы. Я с любой страницы по идее в вашу папку tmp могу залить файл.